# I cannot register new admin panel block Django

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to register my model in admin panel by this code

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from advertisements.models import Advertisement
    
    
@admin.register(Advertisement)
class AdvertisementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

and I just got actually nothing

[image: screenshoot]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using something like:

```py
class AdvertisementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
    
admin.site.register(Advertisement, AdvertisementAdmin)
```